# Regex for 'Title', selected value should start with 'M'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Im using c# and I need to be able to check that the user selects a title from the dropdown list. How would I set the regex to check that the selection starts with M, the values in my dropdown list are Mr, Ms and Mrs. This regex would be used in my customvalidator in Visual Studio 2008 3.5 framework.

Edit: Let me rephrase it, What do i type in my ValidationExpression field for my RegularExpressionValidator Validation type.

[1]: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/836/imglv.jpg "

Comment: How about making the title selection mandatory? As I have read you are in control of the dropdown list items.

Comment: Doctors, priests, the military and peers need not apply.

Comment: This regex is sufficiently simple enough to figure out after 2 minutes at [Regex Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: @Quentin - in light of that comment here is an exhaustive (hopefully) list of titles and suffixes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title

Comment: This is a basic webform to show BASIC skills. Its not something thats meant to be comprehensive and to be used in any real-world situation. But thanks for your harsh feedbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
Regex.IsMatch( inputString, "^M" )
```

That said, it really doesn't sound like a job for regular expressions. You could use `StartsWith`, which is more sane, but what happens when "Mike Smith" registers, and doesn't select a title?

If you want to ensure that a user selected your specific value, then validating the selected value is really what you should do here. Feel free to post more information if that scenario isn't possible.

On a side note, I can't resist posting this quote:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Edit: I missed your edit before I posted. You would be better off using a `RequiredFieldValidator` and setting InitialValue to "Select A Title".

Comment: I posted an Image with my cursor pointing to my issue. I know I can use a method, but im meant to use the Validation drag-drop object.

Comment: @ValianthX - Or if you **really** want Regex: `^M(r|s|iss)\.`. Alternatively `^M.{1,3}?\.` (because some languages, e.g. Afrikaans have their own translated titles like Mnr.).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd401sa.aspx) method, e.g.: `s.StartsWith("M")`.

Or using regex:

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^M")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use startWith :

```
yourString.StartsWith("M");
```

it has also an overload to specify the type of comparison

for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx